# How to solve the coupled system of ODES $\dot{x}=y^2$, $\dot{y}=x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

How to solve the following system of coupled ODEs?

$$ \begin{aligned} \dot{x} &= y^2 \\ \dot{y} &= x \end{aligned} $$

I can see how to solve for their trajectories as $dy/dx$ is of course separable but

1. Is there a transformation I can use to solve this?
2. If so, what is the motivation for the transformation?

Comment: Combining them we get $\ddot{y}= y^2$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413650/solve-y-y2

Comment: It is just as Winther said. $\dot{x}=y^2=\dot{\dot{y}}=\ddot{y}.$ To solve $\ddot{y}=y^2,$ you should multiply by $2\dot{y},$ hence $2\dot{y}\ddot{y}=2y^2\dot{y}=\dot{\dot{y}^2}=\dot{\frac23y^3}.$ This implies $\dot{y}^2=\frac23y^3+C.$

Comment: You should be able to do the rest.

Comment: Also, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y^2}$ is separable, this leads to the same insight.